# Adding one solution with multiple projects outside to git repos from visual studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2019

I have complete software built on .net code and visual studio 19 ver that has both windows and web apps.
On the folder level complete code is inside a C:\Code\source\v2.000 and BuildAll.sln that builds the complete software is C:\Code\source\v2.000_BuildAll\ and .sln references the projects as below

`Project("{GUI-ID}") = "ProjectName", "..\ProjecctPath", "{GUI-ID}" EndProject`

The structure of my solution (.sln) is as below in visual studio

Solution BuildAll

- Lib (Folder)
  Around 50 of projects (.csproj) inside
- Api (Folder)
  4 projects (csproj) inside
- Apps (Folder)
  4 Windows apps projects
- WindowsServices (Folder)
  2 winservice projects
- Web (Folder)
  2 mvc projects

As we migrate to git, when I do File>Add to source control, it gives me error that "Your solution contains files outside solution folders which will not be managed by git" and these are actually inside v2.000 but somewhere in sub folders like \v2.000\libs\ or \v2.000\apps\ or v2.000\coreframework\
Is there a way to put all the code structure to git. I understand, 1 .sln means 1 git, i am not sure why this behaviour/error at visual studio. My reference libraries are not in BuildAll folder but very well inside ..\v2.000. Any help suggestion would be appreciated.

PS: sorry about the long description, did this to make things clear

Comment: Git itself knows nothing about "solutions". Git just stores snapshots of files, in the form of commits. Each commit contains all the files from Git's *index* or *staging area* (see other Q&As about this) and each index entry corresponds to a file in a *working tree*. The working tree must be a single tree-of-files, normally rooted at the same place as the `.git` folder. Any file outside this working tree cannot be stored or manipulated by Git.

Comment: Precisely what all that means with respect to the error message you're getting, I'm not sure, but you'll probably need to re-arrange the files and/or repository in some way.